# slide Toogle not smooth with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery slideToogle function which is not smooth (open / close):
[image]

The beginning of open and close process is good but then it jumps.
Any idea?

```
function toogleWidget() {
   $( ".Widget" ).slideToggle( 1000 );
}
```

css code:

```
.Widget {
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: none;
  width: 450px;
  max-height: 95%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #f9f9fb;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  left: unset !important;
  right: 50px !important;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 999999998;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide *all* / just enough of the code+css to recreate this in a snippet?   It's likely some *other* setting than just the one liner provided.  See [mcve].

Comment: I added the css code. more code isn't available

Comment: It is still not a minimal working example... I have tried to simulate your problem and I think that the "-webkit-transition: all .4s;  transition: all .4s;" are making the movement twitchy.

Comment: @PanVi FYI use backtick ` for code in comments `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is your css:

```
{
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}
```

which says that all transitions should take 0.4s = 400ms, but your slideToggle is for 1000ms so 4/10ths of the way through the animation, it completes.

Remove those two lines.

```js
function toogleWidget() {
   $( ".Widget" ).slideToggle( 1000 );
}

$("#b").click(toogleWidget);
```

```css
.Widget {
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: none;
  width: 450px;
  max-height: 95%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #f9f9fb;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 50px !important;
  /*bottom: 20px;*/
  z-index: 999999998;
  border-radius: 15px;
  /*-webkit-transition: all .4s;*/
  /*transition: all .4s;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='b' type='button'>click me</button>
<hr/>
<div class='Widget'>
...<br/>
...<br/>
...<br/>
...<br/>
...<br/>
...<br/>
...<br/>
</div>
```